# How to set the release version as a part of Ember build?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, source-maps, sentry

I want to set the version on the frontend (a `meta` tag in index.html or a property on `window` once the code is loaded in the browser, or in some other way) as a part of the build/deployment process in Ember. What would be the ideal way to accomplish this? I need this for mapping sourcemaps to versions in Sentry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into this plugin:
[ember-cli-deploy-sentry](https://github.com/dschmidt/ember-cli-deploy-sentry)
Look also at the issues and PRs, at least the source code could get you started.

Answer (score 2):

We use a combination of `ember-cli-app-version` and a Github Action to set this at deployment time and send it with each error report to Sentry.

In our [sentry.js](https://github.com/ilios/frontend/blob/master/app/sentry.js) file we set the error version with:

```
import * as Sentry from '@sentry/browser';
import { Ember } from '@sentry/integrations/esm/ember';
import { versionRegExp } from 'ember-cli-app-version/utils/regexp';

function startSentry(config) {
  Sentry.init({
    ...config.sentry,
    integrations: [new Ember()],
    release: config.APP.version.match(versionRegExp)[0],
  });
}

export {
  startSentry,
};
```

The [github action](https://github.com/ilios/frontend/blob/master/.github/workflows/deploy-production.yml) uses the git tag and looks like:

```
- name: Create a Sentry.io release
      run: |
        # Create new Sentry release
        export SENTRY_RELEASE=$(sentry-cli releases propose-version)
        sentry-cli releases new $SENTRY_RELEASE
        sentry-cli releases set-commits --auto $SENTRY_RELEASE
        sentry-cli releases files $SENTRY_RELEASE upload-sourcemaps tmp/deploy-dist/
        sentry-cli releases finalize $SENTRY_RELEASE
      env:
        SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ember-cli-app-version`](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli-app-version) to display the app version.